# What is the best way to keep track of product sales in an application and pick top selling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, e-commerce

I have setup my databases like this :

Product :

```
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  code           :string
#  name           :string
#  category_id    :integer
...
```

Order items :

```
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  order_id        :integer
#  product_id      :integer
#  color_id        :integer
#  qty             :integer          default("0")
#  price           :money
...
```

Order :

```
#  id                  :integer
#  state               :string
#  placed_on           :datetime
...
```

Now this setup make it really hard for me to pick the `best selling products in each week from each category`. How can I fix this? Another database to keep track of sales? Please help.

Comment: On what condition you define a **best selling products in each week from each category**?

Comment: @Pavan I need to pick the best selling products according to the number of sales. Have to get the number of sales with the Orderitem's qty

Comment: I gave a presentation on this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVzSMhaucUY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you basically need is to join `categories`, `products`, `order_items` and `orders` tables.

Joining can be done with the following code:

```
rel = Category.joins(products: [order_items: :order])
#=> SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."category_id" = "categories"."id" INNER JOIN "order_items" ON "order_items"."product_id" = "products"."id" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."id" = "order_items"."order_id"
```

Based on this you can filter on dates interval.

Let's assume we already have `d1` and `d2` values, which define start and end of the interval we are interested in:

```
rel = rel.where('orders.placed_on >= ? AND orders.placed_on <= ?', d1, d2)
```

Now you can aggregate on fields:

```
result = rel.select('categories.id, categories.name, SUM(order_items.qty) as qty, SUM(order_items.qty * order_items.price) as total')
  .group('categories.id, categories.name')
sample = result.first
sample.id # => 1
sample.name # => "Category 1"
sample.qty  # => 100.0
sample.total # => 500.0
```

Comment: Hey, shouldnt this be a `rel = Category.includes(products: [order_items: :order])`?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple database query to me. The following should be the simple and straight-forward steps to accomplish it.

- Join the three tables
- Filter it by `date`
- Group by `product_id`
- Aggregate the `qty`
- And, sort by aggregated value.

I'm not confident about the method to get the date. Please fill it in yourself in the query below.

```
SELECT P.id, P.name, P.category_id, SUM(qty) as LastWeekSales
FROM Product as P INNER JOIN Order Items as OI 
                    ON P.id = OI.product_id
     INNER JOIN Order as O
                    ON O.id = OI.order_id
WHERE O.placed_on <= GetTodaysDate() AND O.placed_on > GetOneWeekBacksDate()
GROUPBY P.category_id
ORDERBY WeekSales
```

All you need to do is, prepare this query in *ruby-on-rails*. I would do it but I don't know anything about *ruby-on-rails*.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on taking care of this in the model. Here is some working drop-in code if you need it in the meantime. I'm practicing manipulating hashes tonight in case you couldn't tell, ha.

Add to Order model:

```
def self.last_week
  Order.where(" created_at >= ? ", 1.week.ago.utc)
end
```

Add to whatever controller:

```
@qty_hash = category = Hash.new 0; 
@output_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} }

@recently_ordered_items = OrderItem.find_all_by_order_id(Order.last_week)
@recently_ordered_items.each { |i| @qty_hash[i.product_id] += i.qty }
@recent_products=Product.find_all_by_id(@qty_hash.keys)

@qty_hash.each do |key, value|
  @recent_products.each { |i| category = i.category_id if i.id == key }
  @output_hash[category] = @output_hash[category].merge(@qty_hash.slice(key))
end
```

@output_hash is the output and is in the format:
  {1=>{3=>9}, 2=>{4=>8, 6=>5, 7=>4}}

In this case the categories are 1 and 2, product ids are 3 (9 sold), 4 (8 sold), 6 (5 sold), and 7 (4 sold)

Tested and working. Good luck.